# Jenkins generic webhook trigger, multiple invokes at once

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

If I send two or more consecutive invokes to generic webhook trigger with different data in it, I can get data only of the first one.

For example. In GUI "Cause" set to "Triggered on branch $BRANCH of $PROJECT". Two projects A and B send invoke at the same time. In the log I see:

```
Triggered on branch master of A
Triggered on branch master of B
```

Both $BRANCH and $PROJECT are environment variables right now and I try to get it from Job DSL script. Variables set to "master/A". How can I get "master/B" too?

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the readme on Github:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin#trigger-exactly-one-build

Comment: I don't have it checked and even though it deploys multiple builds at once